# Failing if users don't have any files in their home directories

Tags: shell, find, xargs

I have an issue when I am finding files in users directory and deleting them, but I am getting below error "No such file or directory" when there are no files. Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this error?

```
[root@server1 ~]# find /home/*/* -name \* | xargs rm -rf
```

find: ‘/home/*/*’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. ext2 may contain any character other than `\0` and `/` for file names! Think about what would happen, if a user names a file

```
"hi etc"
```

Here, `rm -rf` would receive `etc` as second argument, so if your script is executed in `/`, you'd delete your `/etc` directory. There are options to safely handle file names with spaces, but some of these would fail if the file contains newlines - which of course is equally possible:

```
"hi
etc"
```

`find` has an option to delete files (`-delete`), try to use this. This would also solve your original problem. If that's not possible, read documentation about `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Answer (score -1):

When there are no file, your find search returns "No such file or directory", because when there are no file, the directory structure you describe does not exist. The error is then passed to `rm` with "xargs".

```
find /home/ -name \* | xargs rm -rf
```

should get you the result you're waiting without the warning, as find does not try to build a path that does not exist.

Comment: Yes. I can remove the files/directories successfully but still the error is there that no such file or directory when I executed them again. How can I avoid this error?                                                                                                
 [mak@node1 testscripts]$ find /home/*/* -name \* | xargs rm -rf
[mak@node1 testscripts]$ find /home/*/* -name \* | xargs rm -rf
find: ‘/home/*/*’: No such file or directory
[mak@node1 testscripts]$ find /home/*/* -name \* | xargs rm -rf
find: ‘/home/*/*’: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but working with rm directly seems a good idea to me. Why do you need this "find" before ? You could do something like "rm -rf /home/*", or do you want to only delete files ?

Comment: I am trying to run a weekly cron job where it should delete the user's directories/files in the /home/*/*. I should not get an error if there are no files found.

Comment: Well, if you want to delete all files of all users, "rm -rf /home/*" should be a suiting solution. You don't need the find command.